# Род глагола в подобных случаях относится к подлежащему?

Tags: глаголы

В каком роде было бы верно представить глагол "был" в следующем и подобным ему по конструкции предложениях?

Открытие было вопрос времени.
Открытие был вопрос времени.

Answer (score 2):

***Открытие было вопросом времени.***

Открытие ― подлежащее, связка согласуется в ср. роде с подлежащим.

Именная часть сказуемого  в форме Т.п.

И.п. не подойдет ввиду явного несогласования в роде **рядом стоящих** существительных и глагольной связки.